# Feature Assessment with lowest possible computational effort

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, feature-engineering

**Problem Description**

I have several sensors (assume: 10) of which each measures a different signal from a machine. For each experimental condition and target condition, I have a time-series for each sensor.

Now I compute statistics of this time-series (mean,median,max,min...; assume: 10) - thus I have 10*10 = 100 features for each condition.

The target is to use these features for assessing the machine condition. For each machine condition - and again for each control variable combination - I have 10 measurements.

I have to find the best subset of features which allows predicting the machine condition.

Finally, we aim at minizing the computational effort due to reasons.

**Question**

I would repeatedly use possible subsets of the features as input for a classifier and then chose the best possible subset in a genetic algorithm manner. Yet this approach is too computationally intensive for my application.

The simplest approach that I could think of, is correlation assessment. Yet I am rather sceptical whether correlation assessment helps, as correlation measure linear dependence and therefore makes a strong assumption about the underlying structure of the data.

What alternative methods are known to yield good results regarding feature selection with lowest possible effort (not mine, but the computers)?